# NiFi fails to write to elasticsearch for both HTTP and specific Elasticsearch processor

Tags: elasticsearch, streaming, apache-nifi

I am trying to follow an introductory tutorial for NiFi writing to Elastic.

https://linkbynet.github.io/elasticsearch/tuning/2017/02/07/Bitcoin-ELK-NiFi.html

My Version of NiFi is 1.11.4 (current) and Elastic 7.7.1 (current), respectively as a dockefile: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/7e7426a4d2b2fd363c036d9b12069598.

A full version of the nifi flow xml is also available at https://github.com/geoHeil/streaming-reference/blob/master/for_nifi/conf/flow.xml.gz

I encounter the following problems:

- In `PutElasticsearch5` processor:

  1. `bitstamp-${timestamp:multiply(1000):format(“yyyy-MM-dd”)}` complains about an invalid pattern

```
Query: ${timestamp:multiply(1000):format(“yyyy-MM-dd”)}, transferring to failure: org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.AttributeExpressionLanguageException: Invalid Expression: bitstamp-${timestamp:multiply(1000):format(“yyyy-MM-dd”)} due to Unexpected token '“yyyy-MM-dd”' at line 1, column 34.
```

But the logs of elastic show: `["java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [5.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]",`

````
2. when simplifying the indexing to: `bitstamp-${timestamp}`, fails with:

```
PutElasticsearch5[id=97ed752a-0172-1000-0000-000024edfeac] Failed to insert into Elasticsearch due to None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{9Tgt3qGwSAm5hNsRIEiS-Q}{172.18.0.6}{172.18.0.6:9300}]. More detailed information may be available in the NiFi logs.: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{9Tgt3qGwSAm5hNsRIEiS-Q}{172.18.0.6}{172.18.0.6:9300}]]
```
And the logs keep complaining about an incompatible API. Still, I do not understand where 1) is a parsing failure of the expression langugage initially.
````

When trying to use the HTTP only API to work around the binary incompatibilities (and sticking with (2) to workaround the ):

```
PutElasticsearchHttp[id=9801caaa-0172-1000-ffff-ffffe063c238] Routing to failure due to exception: unexpected end of stream on http://elasticsearch:9300/...: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://elasticsearch:9300/...

nifi_1            | 2020-06-10 19:59:34,717 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.p.e.PutElasticsearchHttp PutElasticsearchHttp[id=9801caaa-0172-1000-ffff-ffffe063c238] Routing to failure due to exception: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://elasticsearch:9300/...: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://elasticsearch:9300/...
nifi_1            | java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://elasticsearch:9300/...
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:236)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.AbstractElasticsearchHttpProcessor.sendRequestToElasticsearch(AbstractElasticsearchHttpProcessor.java:296)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.PutElasticsearchHttp.onTrigger(PutElasticsearchHttp.java:315)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
nifi_1            |     at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
nifi_1            |     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
nifi_1            |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
nifi_1            |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
nifi_1            |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
nifi_1            |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
nifi_1            |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
nifi_1            |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
nifi_1            | Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=24 content=54686973206973206e6f7420616e204854545020706f7274…
nifi_1            |     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:240)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:242)
nifi_1            |     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:213)
nifi_1            |     ... 30 common frames omitted
```

The URI was set to: http://elasticsearch:9300

So I have two questions:

How should NiFi talk to elastic? What is the lateset supported version? Is the HTTP  (slower) way of handling things generally more recommended?
How can I fix the broken expression language string of: `bitstamp-${timestamp:multiply(1000):format(“yyyy-MM-dd”)}`

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6403?jql=project%20%3D%20NIFI%20AND%20text%20~%20%22elasticsearch%207%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) it is a copy-paste bug. When retyping the quotes, it parses the expression nicely.

2) indeed there are incompatibilities in the binary protocol and people are working on this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6403?jql=project%20%3D%20NIFI%20AND%20text%20~%20%22elasticsearch%207%22 ;

in fact, there even seem to be glitches in the HTTP NiFi plugin support. So maybe in some edge cases the manual HTTP processor is needed.

3) the port 9200 is the binary port. switching to 9300 is required.

Comment: be careful with some text editors, this happens all the time to me in my Mac when it changes " to the forward or backward facing quotes...      I have used nifi with ELK many times in production, and I have never had issues and alway use standard port.